# How to make a script auto install under Ubuntu

Tags: installation, cron, tar, packet

I have pretty big assignment where I had to create some files for word frequency checks and a bash script connected with a crontab to make these function run under a specific set of folder every 5 minutes.

The last step here is to somehow compress these folders and scripts so anyone can easily install it on another computer, so some sort of auto installer for these scripts.

I'm not really sure what I should use, if a tarball can achieve this or if I need to use some sort of packet manager to be able to complete this step.

I would be really thankful if someone can explain the best way to complete this, and preferably some links to some documentation about this.

Thank you.

--

Just to clarify,

I need this to some how create the directories and subdirectories like it's looking now, and preferably have something that adds the function automaticly to the crontab record.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do that is a `.deb` package. You would install the cron in `/etc/cron.d/`

You could also use a `shar` and add the commands you need to that. Or use `tar`, let the user extract it in a temp directory then tell them to run an installer. In that installer (which you would write) use either ordinary `cp` commands, or the `install` command.